# Issues after publishing ASP.NET MVC 4 application on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I am facing an issue after publishing my MVC 4 application on windows server 2012 (IIS8). Issue is with System.Web.MVC. When i browse my website it displays an error that referenced version (means System.Web.MVC) is higher. To solve this issue whatever i did is to open the project on live server and remove the System.Web.MVC version and the add the older version of System.Web.MVC. Like if i used System.Web.MVC 4 in local machine then i remove this on server and add System.Web.MVC 3 and the publish but this solution is so frustrating me because whenever i update my application it cause that error.

Please guide me what should i do with this as i am a beginner in .Net technologies.

Comment: what is the .Net framework installed on the server?

Comment: .Net FrameWork 3.5, 4.5 both features are enabled and installed.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1920526.aspx?Installing+MVC+4+on+server

Answer (score 0):

So i got the solution of this issue. Actually this isn't an issue or problem. All i did is to update visual studio and server. My added reference of MVC4 was 4.0.0.1 on my local machine and 4.0.0.0 was on server.
I just update the reference and solve this problem.

Thanks for your support. :)